# Set Calculated Field by Today's Date

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am new to CRM, and I am having trouble creating calculated report columns.

The problem is simple, if the account's Renewal Date field is before the report execution date, the column must say "Delinquent", if not it should say "Good Standing."

When attempting to create the calculated field, CRM only gives me the option to hardcode a date:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other option (besides hard-coding the date), is to change Type=Value to Type=Field and then select a field's value to compare it against.  So if you could accomplish the same thing by comparing the 'ModifiedOn' date (just as an example), you could make that work.  Otherwise, you won't be able to accomplish this using out of the box calculated fields.

CRM can be tricky when trying to do certain things.  One option is to have a workflow that 'waits' for the 'Renewal Date'.  When the workflow executes, you could update the 'Delinquent' field.  You would start the 'timeout' or 'wait' workflow when the 'Renewal Date' is changed or the record is created (whatever suites your needs).  It would take care of it from there.

I know this isn't the most optimal choice, but it is the easiest to throw together really quickly.  Just wanted to mention it incase you get stuck and need something to turn to.

Comment: I had your first solution in mind yesterday as my last backup and it is the best I'm going to get I think. I ended up adding another calculated field that was equal to NOW().